# How can i add receipt first and last name in email tepmplate URL?

Tags: email-template

I have created a visualforce email template. In that I need include a link which should contain  opportunity id. Next to it,first and last  name of receipt.
As of now i am done with opportuniry id.But  i am not sure how to add receipt names to below link.

> http://dev-moveinc.cs14.force.com/ApprovalDetailscopy?id={!Opportunity.Id}.

Example i am sending email to jim lovas.
so link should visible like

> http://dev-moveinc.cs14.force.com/ApprovalDetailscopy?id=006c000000EfkYu&name=jim%20lovas

Answer (score 0):

You would not pass that information in that way. Typically, you would allow the user to select the related record and the recipient type through a lookup on the email selection page. You can do this by navigating to the following URL:

```
{salesforcehost}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={oppId}&retURL=%2F{oppId}&p2_lkid={contactId}&template_id={templateId}
```

You can then use {!recipient.name} to get the contact's name.

You can reference the [visualforce email template guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_creating.htm) for further details on using the merge fields.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @techbusinessman answer:

VF Email Templates are associated with some email action such as:

- Email Alert in workflow or Process Builder
- Apex outbound email messaging
- Manual user action to send an email using the OOB `Send Email` button such as on Activity related lists or Publisher actions

Furthermore, VF Email Templates don't define recipients. Instead, the email action(s) above define the recipients. The VF Email template has access to the recipient and the target object (aka `relatedTo`) and can use both in merge fields

Without knowing more about your use case, you may have other options besides URL hacking to send the email.